# Python onkey not stopping loop

Tags: python, while-loop, nested, turtle-graphics

```
def startgame():
    start.state = False
    print start.state


def restart():
    end.state = False
    start.state = True
    print game.state, end.state


s.listen()

s.onkey(startgame, "Return")

s.onkey(restart, 'r')

# This Loop stops when you hit Enter

while start.state:
    start.enter()
s.reset()

# I tried repeating it here but it doesn't work
while end.state:
    end.enter()
s.reset()
game.state = 'playing'
```

Both loops are nested in a main while loop but the second one is nested in another while loop (If that helps) so it would look something like this

```
while True:
    while start.state:
        start.flash()
    s.reset()
    while True:

        # main game code here

        while end.state:
            end.flash()
        s.reset()
        game.state = 'playing'
        break
```

I simply want it to show the end screen and have 'Press r to play again' flash on screen until the player hits r and then it should restart the game and go back to the start screen. The `end.state` variable wont update during the while loop, but `start.state` does during its while loop.

Comment: Hi Kye! Welcome! Could you tell me more about why you have the nested loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your drawn out (in time) `while` loops have no place in an event-driven environment like turtle.  In general, we need to control everything with events, specifically *timer events*.  Let's rewrite your code as a state machine.  (Since I don't have your object classes, entities like `start.state` become globals like `start_state` in my example code.)

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

start_state = True
end_state = False

def start_game():
    global start_state

    start_state = False

def end_game():
    global end_state

    if not start_state:
        end_state = True

def restart_game():
    global end_state, start_state

    end_state = False
    start_state = True

def flash(text):
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.write(text, align="center", font=('Arial', 24, 'bold'))

    color = turtle.pencolor()
    turtle.pencolor(turtle.fillcolor())
    turtle.fillcolor(color)

def game_states():

    if start_state:
        flash("Start")
    elif end_state:
        flash("End")
    else:
        flash("Playing")

    screen.ontimer(game_states, 500)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.fillcolor(screen.bgcolor())

screen.onkey(start_game, 'Return')
screen.onkey(restart_game, 'r')
screen.onkey(end_game, 'e')
screen.listen()

game_states()

screen.mainloop()
```

The state machine rules are:

```
Start via <Return> -> Playing
Playing via <e> -> End and via <r> -> Start
End via <r> -> Start
```